# Scrapy scrape multiple pages

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a function that can scrape individual page. How can I scrape multiple pages after following corresponding links? Do I need a separate function that calls the parse() like the following gotoIndivPage()? Thank you!

```
import scrapy

class trainingScraper(scrapy,Spider):
   name = "..."
   start_urls = "url with links to multiple pages"

   # for scraping individual page
   def parse(self,response):
      SELECTOR1 = '.entry-title ::text'
      SELECTOR2 = '//li[@class="location"]/ul/li/a/text()'
      yield{
         'title': response.css(SELECTOR1).extract_first(),
         'date': response.xpath(SELECTOR2).extract_first(),
      }

   def gotoIndivPage(self,response):
      PAGE_SELECTOR = '//h3[@class="entry-title"]/a/@href'
      for page in response.xpath(PAGE_SELECTOR):
         if page:
            yield scrapy.Request(
               response.urljoin(page),
               callback=self.parse
            )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally create a new function for every different type of HTML structure I'm trying to scrape. So if your links send you to a page with a different HTML structure then your starting page, I would create a new function and pass that to my callback.

```
 def parseNextPage(self, response): 
   # Parse new page

 def parse(self,response):
       SELECTOR1 = '.entry-title ::text'
       SELECTOR2 = '//li[@class="example"]/ul/li/a/text()'

       yield{
         'title': response.css(SELECTOR1).extract_first(),
         'date': response.xpath(SELECTOR2).extract_first(),
       }
       href = //li[@class="location"]/ul/li/a/@href

       yield scrapy.Request(
           url = href,
           callback=self.parseNextPage
        )
```